# UTF-8 in SQL Server 2008 Database + PHP

Tags: php, sql, database, utf-8

I want to store data with PHP in a MS SQL 2008 Database.

I`ve got problems with letters like ä ö ü ß, they are displayed incorrect in the database and when i display it on the website.

It works when I utf8_encode the data on input and utf8_decode on output the data with PHP.

Is there a other easier way to solve this?

Comment: What's the encoding for your database? What encoding is the text in when you receive it?

Comment: ah i said something wrong, only the words that i typed in directly into the database were displayed wrong. When i save data with php it looks in the database like this asdasdasdÃ¤Ã¤pÃ¶Ã¼Ã¶Ã¶Ã¤0ÃŸ but when i get it from the database with php it is displayed correctly.

Comment: The utf8_encode|decode functions are used to transform from|to ISO-8859-1. That kind of beats the purpose of using Unicode.

Comment: I cant find a good Solution so i just changed the charset of the website to ISO-8859-1 and now everything is fine. ;)

Answer (score 5):

I've solved this once, the problem is that the PHP's mssql driver is broken (can't find the link to bugs.php.net, but it is there) and fails when it comes to nchar and nvarchar fieldsa and utf8. You'll need to convert the data and queries a little bit:

```
SELECT some_nvarchar_field FROM some_table
```

First, you need to change the output to binary - that way it won't get corrupted:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varbinary(MAX), some_nvarchar_field) FROM some_table;
```

Then in PHP, you'll need to convert it to UTF-8 back, there you'll need [iconv extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php)

```
iconv('UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8', $result['some_nvarchar_field']);
```

This fixes selectiong data from database, however, if you want to actually put some data TO the database, or add a `WHERE` clause, you'll still be getting errors, so the fix for `WHERE`, `UPDATE`, `INSERT` and so on is by converting the string to hexadecimal form:
Imagine you have this query:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (some_nvarchar_field) VALUES ('ŽČŘĚÝÁÖ');
```

Now, we'll have to run some PHP:

```
$value = 'ŽČŘĚÝÁÖ';
$value = iconv('UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE', $value); //convert into native encoding 
$value = bin2hex($value); //convert into hexadecimal
$query = 'INSERT INTO some_table (some_nvarchar_field)  VALUES(CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), 0x'.$value.'))';
```

The query becomes this:

```
INSERT INTO some_table (some_nvarchar_field) VALUES (CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), 0x7d010c0158011a01dd00c100d600));
```

And that **will work**!

I've tested this with MS SQL server 2008 on Linux using FreeTDS and it works just fine, I've got some huge websites runing on this with no issues what so ever.

Comment: Or, you know, when I read your question once again, that might be a lot simpler issue :-)

Comment: mh i think thats a little bit more work then just encode and decoode? ;D But thanks

Comment: As I wrote before, this might be a solution to a whole different problem, I must have misread your question at first :-)

Comment: ok np ^^ Anybody know where i can see or change the charset of the SQL Database in the Management studio?

Comment: Thank you very much for "how to write value"! Your "select" doesn't work, here's working variant: http://davidwalsh.name/php-odbc-nvarchar  (`SELECT CAST(CAST([field] AS VARCHAR(8000)) AS TEXT)`)I use your select and his write and it works fine :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I searched for two days how to insert UTF-8 data (from web forms) into MSSQL 2008 through PHP. I read everywhere that you can't, you need to convert to UCS2 first (like cypher's solution recommends).
On Windows environment SQLSRV said to be a good solution, which I couldn't try, since I am developing on Mac OSX.

However, FreeTDS manual (what PHP mssql uses on OSX) says to add a letter "N" before the opening quote:

```
mssql_query("INSERT INTO table (nvarcharField) VALUES (N'űáúőűá球最大的采购批发平台')", +xon);
```

According to this discussion, N character tells the server to convert to Unicode.
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/155859/why-do-we-need-to-put-n-before-strings-in-microsoft-sql-server

Answer (score -1):

i can insert by code

```
    $value = $_POST['first_name'];
    $value = iconv("UTF-8","UCS-2LE",$value);
    $value2 = $_POST['last_name'];
    $value2 = iconv("UTF-8","UCS-2LE",$value2);  
    $query = "INSERT INTO tbl_sample(first_name, last_name) VALUES (CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '".$value."') , CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), '".$value2."'))"; 

    odbc_exec($connect, $query);
```

if i can not search